# Late 2008 MacBook Pro no longer wakes up on its own

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, power, system-settings

Plain and simple here: about one week ago, my MacBook Pro stopped adhering to its wake schedule. I have had it set to wake every weekday at 6 a.m. for as long as I can remember. It has done so with 100% reliability as long as a power source is plugged in and the lid is open. Then it stopped. I finally went and checked the power savings pref pane this morning, and all is right with the world. I tweak my computer all the time, but have not done anything with this setting, nor have I installed anything that was advertised to affect power management. That being said, should I reset the SMC? This doesn't really seem to fall under what [apple would normally recommend this for](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964?viewlocale=en_US).

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to the SMC or the PRAM. The System Management Controller controls everything related to power on your Mac. I would reset this first, and then [reset the PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379) right after. Let us know if that works. You may have to reset the sleep schedule after resetting the PRAM.

Comment: I'll reset SMC tonight and see if that does anything before I reset PRAM. I'll post tomorrow with an update.

Comment: Spontaneous remission. I woke up this morning and it was on, as scheduled, without resetting SMC. Not sure what's up, but thanks for the reply, and I'll definitely give SMC reset a go if it acts up again.